# most performant way to get asof price given a list of timestamps

Tags: kdb

I have a list of timestamps spanning multiple dates ( no sym, just timestamps). These can be 1000/2000 at times, spanning multiple dates.

What's the most performant way to hit an hdb and get the closest price available for each timestamp?

select from hdbtable where date = x -> can be over 60mm rows.

To do this for each date and then an aj on top is very poor.

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most performant way to aj, assuming the HDB follows the standard conventions of date-partitioned with `p# attribute on sym, is

```
aj[`sym`time;select sym,time,other from myTable where …;select sym,time,price from prices where date=x]
```

There should be no additional filters/where-clause on the prices table other than date.

You're saying you have no syms just timestamps but what does that mean? Does that mean you want the price of all syms at that timestamp or you want the last price of *any* sym at that timestamp? The former is easy as you can just join your timestamps to your distinct sym list and use that as the "left" table in the aj. The latter will not be as easy as the HDB data likely isn't fully sorted on time, it's likely sorted by sym and then time. In that case you might have to again join your timestamps to your distinct sym list and aj for the price for all syms and from that result take the one with the max time.

So I guess it depends on a few factors. More info might help.

EDIT: suggestion based on further discussion:

```
targetTimes:update targetTime:time from ([]time:"n"$09:43:19 10:27:58 13:12:11 15:34:03);
res:aj0[`sym`time;(select distinct sym from trade where date=2021.01.22)cross targetTimes;select sym,time,price from trade where date=2021.01.22];

select from res where not null price,time=(max;time)fby targetTime
sym  time                 targetTime           price
----------------------------------------------------
AQMS 0D09:43:18.999937967 0D09:43:19.000000000 4.5
ARNA 0D10:27:57.999842638 0D10:27:58.000000000 76.49
GE   0D15:34:02.999979520 0D15:34:03.000000000 11.17
HAL  0D13:12:10.997972224 0D13:12:11.000000000 18.81
```

This gives the price of whichever sym is closest to your targetTime. Then you would `peach` this over multiple dates:

```
{targetTimes: ...;res:aj0[...];select from res ...}peach mydates;
```

Note that what's making this complicated is your requirement that it be the price of *any* sym that's closest to your sym-less targetTimes. This seems strange - usually you would want the price of sym(s) as of a particular time, not the price of anything closest to a particular time.

Comment: any sym at that time is fine. our input is a list of timestamps. We want to get *any* price that matches the input timestamp the closest. the list of timestamps wont match what's in the price table

Comment: how can i do an aj on a sym when i dont have one on the left hand side of the aj?

Comment: I'm suggesting you fabricate a sym column in the left hand table corresponding to syms in the right hand table. Though this presumes the right hand table has syms and has parted attribute on that. So question - what column (if any) has a parted ( `p# ) attribute in the right hand table? In other words, what are the prices *of*? Also, is the hdb table date-partitioned?

Comment: yes its parted on sym and date partitioned. so are you saying I should do something like select distinct sym from table where date = x  and then attach to the timestamps for each date with a cross product?

Comment: Exactly yes. Selecting distinct syms for a given date will be very quick, cross with timestamps will be quick, aj will then be optimal and the final select of max time will be quick. You would still have to do it one date at a time of course but peach and slaves can help you then

Comment: so for a single date:  syms: select distinct sym from table where date = x; res: aj[ `sym`time; ([] time: timesOfCertainDate) cross syms; select from table where date = x]; res: select from res where  time=(max;time) fby sym ? is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multithreading to optimize your query, with each thread being assigned a date to process, essentially utilising more than just one core:

```
{select from hdbtable where date = x} peach listofdates
```

More info on multithreading can be found [here](https://code.kx.com/q/wp/multi-thread/), and more info on peach can be found [here](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/peach/)